# Mandar a través de un parametro o una constante una ruta especifica al web.xml para subir archivos

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

Mi duda es si hay manera de enviar una constante o un parametro al web.xml 
WEB.xml

*

> ```
>     <filter>
>        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
>       <init-param>
>       <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
>       <param-value>1048576</param-value>
>      </init-param>
>      <init-param>
>     <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
>       <param-value>/ruta/to/dir/tmp</param-value>   </init-param>   </filter>
> ```

*

La ruta que quiero controlar a través de una constante de java es la que se encuentra en la uploadDirectory /ruta/to/dir/tmp ya que si se quiere cambiar o crear una nueva se debe de setear la ruta al web.xml, Me gustaría conocer si hay manera de enviar esta ruta a través de un parámetro o una constante para así poder controlar las carpetas donde se almacenan los archivos temporales de primefaces, sin necesidad de subir y bajar el war deployado.

Answer (score 0):

El fichero `web.xml` es el Descriptor de Despliegue de la aplicación y es utilizado por el servidor de aplicaciones (Tomcat, por ejemplo) en el momento de despliegue de la aplicación. La aplicación en sí misma no accede al `web.xml`, por lo que no puedes configurarlo con una constante.

Por otra parte, no es necesario que subas y bajes el war para consultar el web.xml, este estará accesible en la ruta de despliegue de la aplicación. Para cambiar la ruta, te bastaría con modificar el fichero y reiniciar el servidor de aplicaciones.